# Mysql Caluclate Total Stock IN & OUT From Multiple Tables Based on Date

Tags: mysql, select

In a single query, I need to separately sum volume for each product on both Purchase & Order group by Product filtered by Date.

For e.g., I need to know how much volume I purchased and how much volume was ordered of a product till year 2017 and month 12.

Like:

- **Product** | **Volume Purchased** | **Order Received**
- Rose facewash | 50 | 22
- Leather Bag | 32 18

This is Product Table, to store details of product.

```
CREATE TABLE t_product
(
    pkey INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cname VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL,
);
```

This is Purchase Table,to store the basic details of purchase like bill id and date.

```
CREATE TABLE t_purchase
(
    pkey INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cdated DATETIME NOT NULL,
);
```

This is Purchase Detail where details of every Product purchased is stored

```
CREATE TABLE t_purchase_detail
(
    pkey INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rpurchase INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    rproduct INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    crate DECIMAL(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cdiscount DECIMAL(5,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ctax DECIMAL(5,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cvolume INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT t_purchase_detail_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (rpurchase) REFERENCES t_purchase (pkey),
    CONSTRAINT t_purchase_detail_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY (rproduct) REFERENCES t_product (pkey)
);
CREATE INDEX rproduct ON t_purchase_detail (rproduct);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX rpurchase ON t_purchase_detail (rpurchase, rproduct);
```

This is Order table where basic details of Order Received is stored like order id and date

```
CREATE TABLE t_order
(
    pkey INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cdated DATETIME NOT NULL,
);
```

This is Order Detail where details of every Product ordered is stored

```
CREATE TABLE t_order_detail
(
    pkey INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rproduct INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    rorder INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    csale DECIMAL(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cdiscount DECIMAL(5,2) unsigned DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
    ctax DECIMAL(5,2) unsigned DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
    cvolume SMALLINT(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT t_order_detail_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (rorder) REFERENCES t_order (pkey),
    CONSTRAINT t_order_detail_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (rproduct) REFERENCES t_product (pkey)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX roder ON t_order_detail (rorder, rproduct);
CREATE INDEX rproduct ON t_order_detail (rproduct);
```

- pkey is the Primary key or Id in all tables.
- pkey of Product table is Foreign key in Purchase Details and Order Details tables as rproduct.
- pkey of Purchase Table is Foreign key in Purchase Details table as rpurchase
- pkey of Order Table is Foreign key in Order Details table as rorder

**EDIT**

This is the query I'm running:

```
SELECT
  t_product.cname                AS name,
  sum(t_purchase_detail.cvolume) AS volume,
  sum(t_order_detail.cvolume)    AS sold
FROM t_product, t_purchase, t_purchase_detail, t_order, t_order_detail
WHERE t_purchase.cgst = 1
      AND (t_product.pkey = t_purchase_detail.rproduct AND t_product.pkey = t_order_detail.rproduct)
      AND (t_purchase.pkey = t_purchase_detail.rpurchase AND t_order.pkey = t_order_detail.rorder)
      AND (
        (YEAR(t_purchase.cdated) <= 2017 AND MONTH(t_purchase.cdated) <= 12)
        AND
        (YEAR(t_order.cdated) <= 2017 AND MONTH(t_order.cdated) <= 12)
      )
GROUP BY t_product.pkey
ORDER BY name;
```

This is selecting common products from Purchase Details and Order Details Tables. But there are cases where some products are available only in Purchase Details table and some only in Order Details table. If a product is missing in one of a Table it but present in another, then it's volume from that table should be calculated as 0. For e.g., if total 30 units of Orange Facewash is purchased and none is ordered, output should be

- Orange Facewash | 30 | 0

and vice-versa.

**EDIT 2**

This query returns all products including the one which are not present in both list.

```
SELECT
  t_product.pkey            AS key_s,
  t_product.cname           AS NAME,

  (SELECT sum(t_purchase_detail.cvolume)
   FROM t_product, t_purchase, t_purchase_detail
   WHERE t_product.pkey = key_s
         AND t_product.pkey = t_purchase_detail.rproduct
         AND t_purchase.pkey = t_purchase_detail.rpurchase
         AND YEAR(t_purchase.cdated) <= 2017 AND MONTH(t_purchase.cdated) <= 12
   GROUP BY t_product.pkey) AS volume,

  (SELECT sum(t_order_detail.cvolume) AS sold
   FROM t_product, t_order, t_order_detail
   WHERE t_product.pkey = key_s
         AND t_product.pkey = t_order_detail.rproduct
         AND t_order.pkey = t_order_detail.rorder
         AND YEAR(t_order.cdated) <= 2017 AND MONTH(t_order.cdated) <= 12
   GROUP BY t_product.pkey) AS sold

FROM t_product
GROUP BY t_product.pkey
ORDER BY NAME;
```

I need a way to write this more efficiently in a clean single query which can remove the products not present in any of Details table.

Thank you

Comment: OK spec, But I would add your attempt otherwise folk might suspect you want them to do your job for you.

Comment: Normally I would have a sub query which selects distinct product from both tables (ie creating a master list) and then join all the required tables to this.

Comment: @P.Salmon. Please see my EDIT 2. Can you please write this in an elegant way so that it will contain only those products who are present in both or at-least one Details table